# How to use exec inside eval command?

Tags: perl, eval

I have set the WORKAREA to some path and in Perl code I have defined like this:

```
eval 'exec $ENV{'WORKAREA'}/some/path'
if 0;
```

I am getting error that path  `$ENV{'WORKAREA'}/some/path` is not defined. Anyone know to define this?

Comment: You have single quotes inside single quotes. Try using double quotes like this: `eval "exec $ENV{'WORKAREA'}/some/path"`

Comment: Quoting aside, what is `exec $ENV{'WORKAREA'}/some/path` supposed to do?! There seems to be some quoting and concatenation missing there.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to run a program program called `/some/path` that lives in your work area, capture its output and then run that as Perl code in your current program. Security concerns aside, [`exec`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec) never returns. So if you want to do what I think you want to do, you will need `qx//`. But again, that's a really bad thing to be doing. If however you want to maybe trap errors, then you need the block form of `eval`: `eval { exec "$ENV{WORKAREA}/some/path" }`. But since `exec` never returns, there's no error to trap either.

Comment: Your whole line of code can never be executed at all, since it ends with `if 0`. Any command before that will not be executed. Exactly as if you had a line `if (0) { ... }`.

Comment: Also, this is a horrible solution, whatever your problem is. This is a classic XY-problem.

Comment: Altogether -- can you explain, in words and clearly, what you want to do?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't result in the error you mention. It doesn't even compile. And if it didn't, the `eval` wouldn't be executed. Please provide the code you've actually run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are copying there, but there are a few problems.

First, look inside the string that you give to `eval`. It's not valid Perl:

```
exec $ENV{'WORKAREA'}/some/path
```

You're trying to construct the string that represents the path to the program you want to `exec`, so quote the whole thing (like any other string):

```
exec "$ENV{'WORKAREA'}/some/path"
```

or even better, use generalized quoting so you won't have to escape something later:

```
exec q($ENV{'WORKAREA'}/some/path)
```

Note that I used `q()` here. You don't want that string to interpolate because that variable will have already been interpolated by the string you give to `eval`:

```
eval "exec q($ENV{'WORKAREA'}/some/path)"
```

I'm not sure why you `eval` this though. Maybe you think that the `eval` will shield you from some magic. But, `exec` isn't doing anything that magical. It's presence in your program shouldn't affect anything else:

```
if( 0 ) { # why are you doing this?
   exec "$ENV{'WORKAREA'}/some/path"
   }
```